# Can not make the Objective-C function CFNotificationCenterAddObserver work in command line

Tags: objective-c

I want to get notified when my input method get changed on MacOS, so I have these code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

void notificationCallback (CFNotificationCenterRef center, void * observer, CFStringRef name, const void * object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", "abc");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    CFNotificationCenterRef center =  CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();

    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center, NULL, notificationCallback,
                                    kTISNotifySelectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged, NULL,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
    while(1) {
    }
}
```

and compile it with

```
/usr/bin/clang -framework foundation -framework carbon -o im-select im-select.m
```

It could compile, but I would never get feedback after run `im-select` and change my input method.

These code works well in an app, I just don't know why it couldn't work in command line.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is blocking the main thread but the notification is delivered to the main thread. See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543316-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver?language=objc):

> Notification delivery is registered for the main thread.

Thus, your application can not receive notifications. You should use a runloop and a timer for waiting of the notification.